# How to press the Physical Button (like volume or power button ) in Android Pragmatically

Tags: android, keyboard-shortcuts

Like the combination of power button and volume down button - takes a screenshot of the phone...

Similarly I am trying to access volume up and power button with long press in my app and provide a shortcut. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to take the screen shot of UR app screen?

Comment: @fahim... yes ..but i have tried the screenshot code from this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android
and it is not working so i am trying for the alternative

Comment: I am also using this but it works, will you share your code

Comment: @fahim.. it is capturing the bitmap but the thing is i am changing the value of alpha in the bitmap so the bitmap it captured is not like that it looks on image view in running app so i am wondering if some how i get the screenshot pragmatically.